# Switch bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

Using the simple built in bibliography (bibtex) tool, how do I switch the citation style to be APA, MLA, or Chicago style? The code looks somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sources}

\end{document}
```

It seems like changing my style from `plain` is what I want, but looking at this [link](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html) makes it seem like just a bunch of different styles, and I'll have to mix and match (there is an "apa" style, but no mla as far as I can tell.

Is there a way to just tell bibtex to conform to apa, mla, or chicago style easily? (I don't need all three but it would be great to know how to switch between them quickly).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to combine two separate objectives. First, how to switch from one bib style to another; second, how to get the "perfect" style. To achieve the former, changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle` is indeed the way to go. To achieve the latter, it would really be helpful if you indicated in more detail which parts of each of the styles is not correct, according to your view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you indeed have to change it in `\bibliographystyle{}` directive.  You can also look [here](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/beitzel/beitzel.pdf) to get more APA specific information.

Comment: So it seems from this cite that it's not possible with bibtex, all of the examples had some form of APA violation with it?

Comment: You may want to start the document with `\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}` or something similar.